# rewrite rules for utm_source parameter in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

guys, i have question on mod_rewrite function.

this is outside link like

```
http://example.com/article?utm_sources=baidu&utm_campain=alading
```

I like to change it to

```
http://example.com/article#utm_sources=baidu&utm_campain=alading
```

#utm_sources=xxx also can be traced by Google GA code

I try below code but not working

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^utm_source(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article$ /article?%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

how do i make rewrite rules for it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_sources=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article/?$ /article#%{QUERY_STRING}? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Trailing `?` is required to strip off previous query string.

Comment: hi, anubhava, thanks provide this, but i test it on here
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ not working.

Answer (score 1):

I update with below rules it works for me, but thanks [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) give answer.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}#%{QUERY_STRING}? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```